# Distance between 2 copper rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

A balance was used to investigate the relationship between current and force. The
balance was set up with one copper rod fixed to it and a second rod fixed above it, as
shown in the diagram. Each rod was connected to a source of current. The diagram is
not to scale.

[image]

The copper rods were rigid, each was 2.6 m long, and they were parallel. The current
in the upper rod was kept constant at 50 A. Different currents were passed through the
lower rod and the balance reading recorded for each current. The readings are given
in the table below.

[image]

My question is: how would you calculate the distance between the 2 copper rods?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Where did this come from? I'm curious because this is related to the way unit current has to be defined, but it's probably all about to change. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

First find the actual weight of the rod by switching off the current.
When current flows the Electronic balance will give reading = Weight-(Force on rod)/9.8
Force on the rod depends upon the distance between them and upon the currents passing through the two wires. [Force per unit length is given by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law#Equation): $
  F_m = 2 k_A \dfrac {I_1 I_2 } {r}$ .
 Multiply $F_m$ with the total length of the copper rod to get force of attraction b/w the rods. Calculate $r$ for diffferent values of current. Calculate the average value of $r$ this will be the seperation b/w the two rods.

Comment: Just to add that if this is a paper-only exercise, the weight of the rod can be inferred by extrapolating the value for I=0 of a linear fit for the data.

Comment: @Peltio Good point. $r$ is constant. Reading of balance machine varies linearly with $I$.